# Laravel 5.8: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have a table called `user_wallet` like this:

[image]

Then at the Controller, I tried this:

```
try {
    if ($request->pay_wallet == '1') {
        $us_id = Auth()->user()->usr_id;
        $user_wallet = UserWallet::find('user_id', $us_id);
        dd($user_wallet);
    }
}catch (\Exception $e) {
    dd($e);
}
```

But I get this error:

**SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2' in 'field list' (SQL: select `2` from `user_wallet` where `user_wallet`.`id` = user_id limit 1)**

However as you can see in the picture, there are two wallets with the `user_id` of 2.

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the find method only works on **id**  so it's better to use where clause

```
$user_wallet = UserWallet::where('user_id', $us_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `find()` wrong, this method accepts only one paramater, it is the value of the primary key you want to find. Because you are in a pivot table and there is no id present,
you will have to use `firstWhere('user_id', $us_id)` for the first occurrence  or you will have to rewrite the find() method for the pivot table.

But please be aware that a user could have multiple wallets, so it might be better to ask them which wallet to use.

Comment: Call to undefined method App\UserWallet::firstWhere()

Comment: @tejoslaeslio: I guess you use laravel version below 6.*, then use `UserWallet::where('user_id', $us_id)->first();`